# mongodb trying to drop a collection that might not exist

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm getting:

```
(node:78465) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoError: ns not found
```

My code:

```
  delete(projectId) {
    if (!this.db) return
    this.db.collection(projectId, (err, collection) => {
      // err is null here.
      collection.drop();
    });
  }
```

How do I make sure I don't get the error if the collection doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use promises:

```
this.db.collection(projectId).drop().then(function () {
  // success
}).catch(function () {
  // error handling
})
```

Answer (score 0):

So ns `namespace` error would come up when trying do something with a collection that does not exists. With your code you could do:

```
 delete(projectId) {
    if (!this.db) return;
    this.db.collection(projectId).drop((err, dropOK) =>{
    if (err) {
          console.error("There is an error::", err);
          return;
        }

    if (dropOK) console.log("Collection deleted");
   });
}
```

Some points from understanding the problem:

- `db.colletion(anyString)` would just return the interface with
  `anyString` sitting inside the namespace & all the action definitions
  that you might want to execute with that collection.
- So with **error first callback** on `db.collection(anyString, (e,res))` `e` will be `null` only and result would be passed to `res` as long as `db` is alive.
- And that is why `db.collection()` itself is not an `async` function and the callback isn't really needed.
- It is the action like `collection.drop()` that is `async` goes to drop it but doesn't find it and hence the `error`.
- And `drop()` is the actual one that needs a **callback** with `error` to identify.

Comment: There is no err if it doesn't exist.

Comment: @Harry Yes! I have tried to explain some of the points w.r.t that in the answer from what i understand. Do correct me if I am missing something. Thanks!

Comment: I understand what you're saying and I agree that db.collection is not async. But that still gives the error of dropping a non-existent collection.

Comment: Yeah that error is from the call of `drop()` it goes to drop a collection that you have explicitly set via `db.collection()` but doesn't really find it and throws the error. And this was an `async` op hence the unhandled promise rejection. Isn't it?

Comment: It'll always throw the error, if you use promises you can catch the error. I ended up posting the answer, thanks for your help though.

Comment: You don't really have to use promises, I understand it's a neater/better way of doing it but callback would catch the error all the same in the if clause if at all.